# Software Center Missing Icons

Tags: software-installation

Installed Elementary Freya this week and noticed that many of my Software Center Icons are missing. Is this a known issue?

[image]

Comment: Its probably a bug, try searching it in launchpad

Comment: FYI It took my software center several seconds to load in a new list of programs and corresponding icons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1417347). Not sure will it be resolved or not since the elementary team is working on developing its own application centre for the next release.